# How can I run a program and watch its activity using top?

Tags: programming, console, top

I have a small program which I compiled myself. It’s CPU intensive, so I want to watch the CPU usage when it’s working.

However, when I run `./myprog`, I can’t run `top` immediately and sequentially.

Comment: Although not answer to your question, try using profiler tool relevant to your language. This will give you much better idead what's going on, rather than checking program's wall time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run it in background:

```
./myprogram &
```

To resume it from background use the fg command, for example:

```
fg 1
```

To see all jobs in background, run the jobs command:

```
jobs
```

Answer (score 8):

Another suggestion: open a new tab on your terminal emulator.

Comment: This, I would say, is _the_ way to do it, since 1988 or so when our 80x24 text terminals were replaced by screens with xterm windows on them. (But I would use a window, not one of those newfangled tab thingies!)

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1. send it in background ([see @Panta's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/595900/16395)) if you can; this is not possible or messy if the program need to do input/output on the console;
2. use another virtual console (by default, you have 6); you can switch with `ctrl`-`alt`-`F1` to `F6` and login;
3. Use a terminal multiplexer like [tmux](http://www.sitepoint.com/tmux-a-simple-start/) or [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen).

Answer (score 0):

pidstat might be useful for you, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Since your program is so CPU hungry, run top first in one terminal screen and `./myprog` in a second terminal screen (or tab as mentioned). Since top is already running at this point `./myprog` won't interfere with it starting up.